# How do you retrieve an ID from a phone number?

Tags: android, android-contacts, phone-number

I am trying to retrieve ***Phone*** Number hence using

```
String addrWhere = Contacts.Phones.NUMBER + " = " + userNumber;
  String id = "";
  Cursor c = mContext.getContentResolver().query(
    Contacts.Phones.CONTENT_URI,
    new String[] { Contacts.Phones._ID }, addrWhere, null, null);
  try {
   if (c.getCount() > 0) {
    c.moveToFirst();
    id = c.getString(0);
    Log.i("IDS", id);
   }
  } finally {
   c.close();
  }
  return id;
```

Can anyone let me know my mistake in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HI Every one...
thanks for reply!!! @ Sotapanna
well i found the answer as pointed by Sotapanna

pasting the working code for anyone who needs it!

```
private String findID(String userNumber) {
        Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri
                .encode(userNumber));
        int id = 0;
        String[] returnVals = new String[] { PhoneLookup._ID };
        Cursor pCur = mContext.getContentResolver().query(uri, returnVals,
                PhoneLookup.NUMBER + " = \"" + userNumber + "\"", null, null);
        if (pCur.getCount() > 0) {
            pCur.moveToFirst();
            id = pCur.getColumnCount();
            if (id >= 0) {
                id = pCur.getInt(0);
            }
        }

        Log.i("Contacts", "" + id);
        return String.valueOf(id);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the solution to [How to query ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486569/how-to-query-contactscontract-commondatakinds-phone-on-android) which is usage of [ContactsContract.PhoneLookup](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.html) provider:

```
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
resolver.query(uri, new String[]{PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME,...
```

Comment: Please quote relevant bits rather than just a link (definitely *include* the link, but *also* quote): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers